# BIRT import error in java eclipse with GWT

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

kinda confused about the error I'm getting. I'm using the report engine of BIRT and I've done some sample code and a sample report inside of GWT, using the BIRT servlet example. I've imported all the BIRT 4.3.0 jars into my program via java build path > add external jars, including BIRT 4.3.0 zip itself, as well as dragging and dropping them into WEB-INF/lib. I don't get any errors in my code and all my imports seem fine, yet i I still get this error when running the program

```
    [ERROR] [ioma] - Line 5: The import org.eclipse.birt cannot be resolved
```

I've cleaned the project multiple times and removed and re-added my jar's still no luck. Not sure at all why I am getting this error, any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Forgot that if I'm using BIRT it has to be server side, so the code to generate the reports has to be server side, I had them on client side, moving them to the correct location solved my problem.